# Infinispan server : how to use it

Tags: infinispan-9

I am starting to study infinispan and infinispan client/server mode.
I focus on server mode.
I use version 9.4.15. I am successful in launching to server in clustered mode, with following commands :

```
bin\standalone.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=0 -Djboss.node.name=nodeA  -c clustered.xml
bin\standalone.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000 -Djboss.node.name=nodeB  -c clustered.xml
```

I have added an admin user, so I can access my 2 servers web IHM, with 
http://127.0.0.1:9990 and http://127.0.0.1:10990

Servers see them and I think that they are in same cluster.

Servers are configured (by default) with 2 caches named "Dist" and "Repl" in  CacheContainer named "clustered".

My 3 points :

1. When trying to open cluster definition, IHM is sticked with a loading icon,
   No stacktrace or ERROR in log stdOutput.
   [sticked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OFKv.png)
2. When trying to insert key in one of Dist or Repl cache from server NodeA, operation return a 401 not authorized ... I don't know how to solve this.
3. I am successful to user CommandLine Client to access my cluster, but I don't know how to insert something in a cache. I've not found a lot of documentation about it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

However, I have been successful in creating a HotRod client to connect standalone server or cluster of servers, and put some entries in Dist and Repl caches.

**I'm still unable to open cluster definition in "Infinispan Server Managment Console" ...**

However, the 2 servers log well that NodeA and NodeB are together :

```
Finished rebalance with members [nodeA, nodeB], topology id 6
```

Is there a problem with Server Managment Console ? (it is angular js)

I have no usable logs from server (stacktrace, or ERROR) ; 
The only error I can see come from webbrowser console : a HTTP 500 response with

```
{
    "outcome" : "failed",
    "failure-description" : "WFLYCTL0202: No known child type named host",
    "rolled-back" : true
}
```

when angular sends a POST request http://127.0.0.1:9990/management with payload :

```
{
  address: [],
  child-type: "host",
  operation: "read-children-resources"
}
```

Does someone explain me if it is an issue or if I miss something ... ?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. I'm able to have both hostA and hostB join the cluster, however I'm getting http 500 - "WFLYCTL0202: No known child type named host" when attempting to view the cluster in http://localhost:9990/console/index.html#/server-groups

Comment: The issue does look to be that there's no hosts in the address for that call. I've opened an issue https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-console

Comment: this is supposed to be fixed with infinspan 9.4.18 final https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-console/issues/5

Comment: Supposed to be, but still isn't.